# Looking for software / tool to shuffle alphabets / characters in text file

Tags: text-processing, plain-text, text, ascii

Looking for software / tool to shuffle alphabets / characters in text file,

Requirements:

- use 1 password to shuffle and de-shuffle
- correct password will de-shuffle the text file into its original version
- incorrect password will de-shuffle the text file into random fake version

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is known as deniable encryption.

From my research with those terms, linux has the most powerful implementation, allowing for one to have an alternative decryption, but not necessarily destruction of the original encrypted information on incorrect passwords.

My research indicates that over the last fifteen to twenty years (wiki links, SE links, reddit posts), destruction on incorrect password is not available.

The first answer in the [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34684/truly-deniable-encryption) is quite comprehensive and covers the generalities in my opening paragraphs, yet does not include destructive password failure.

I've found another [trove of information](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/information-security/plausible-deniability-encryption/) using "deniable encryption software with destruction" as the search terms. It's quite comprehensive and covers a number of sociological considerations, not valid to your question. The most applicable portion covers using Kali Linux:

> Another solution is to set up the data to self-destruct if a certain
> key is entered, using the Kali Linux feature. If you are captured by
> your adversary, you can simply give them the self-destruct key, and
> the data from the device will be unrecoverable. However, this method
> only works if your attacker didn’t have the foresight to copy the data
> first, which any technically proficient adversary should do.

Quoted from linked site. The link on the site for Kali Linux feature results in 404, but the main option bar atop the screen has working links. Again, linux, not windows. I did not research it to determine if it was file, partition, or drive encryption and destruction.